# Subtract Two RDD contains List As Value in Spark/Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala. I have two RDD of below type :

> RDD[(Long, List[Long])]

I want to subtract value inside **List[Long]** from two RDD.

For Example:

rddPair1 contains :

```
((4,List(5)), (1,List(2)), (2,List(4, 3, 4)), (3,List(6, 4)))
```

rddPair2 contains :

```
((5,List(6)), (2,List(3)), (3,List(4)))
```

I want resultant RDD Something like below :

```
(4,List(5)), (1,List(2)), (2,List(4, 4)), (3,List(6))
```

You can check here **2 , 3**  keys matches and for this keys List value of rddPair2 gets subtracted from value of rddPair1.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `leftOuterJoin` and then map the results to get the desired format:

```
val result: RDD[(Int, List[Int])] = rddPair1.leftOuterJoin(rddPair2).mapValues {
  case (l1, Some(l2)) => l1.diff(l2) // match found - remove l2 from l1
  case (l1, None) => l1              // no match  - keep l1 as is
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tzach Zohar. It is very usefull to me and others as well.